# In R: get multiple rows by splitting a column using tidyr and reshape2

Tags: r, split, reshape2, tidyr

What is the most simpel way using `tidyr` or `reshape2` to turn this data:

```
data <- data.frame(
      A=c(1,2,3),
      B=c("b,g","g","b,g,q"))
```

Into (e.g. make a row for each comma separated value in variable `B`):

```
  A B
1 1 b
2 1 g
3 2 g
4 3 b
5 3 g
6 3 q
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(data, 'B', ',', 'long')
```

Or using `base R`

```
lst <- setNames(strsplit(as.character(data$B), ','), data$A)
stack(lst)
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
 unnest(lst,A)
```

Comment: splitstackshape pkgs is indeed what I needed!