# Replicate each row of data.frame when occurrence

Tags: r, database, code-duplication

I am facing a tricky question and would be glad to have some help.

I have a data frame with an ID name taking different structures. Something like this following :

```
ID
bbb-5p/mi-98/6134
abb-4p
bbb-5p/mi-98
```

Every time I have this "/" I would like to duplicate the row. Each row should be duplicated the number of time we find this "/". 
Then the name of the duplicated row should be the root + the characters right after the "/".

For exemple this :

```
ID
bbb-5p/mi-98/6134
```

should give :

```
ID
bbb-5p
bbb-5p-mi-98
bbb-5p-6134
```

Also my initial data frame have 5 variables :

```
  [ID, varA, varB, varC, varD]
```

And every time I have this "/" I would like to duplicate the entire row. Then I am expecting to have a new data frame with something like

```
  newID         newvarA  newvarB  newvarC  newvarD   
  bbb-5p        varA(1)  varB(1)  varC(1)  varD(1)
  bbb-5p-mi-98  varA(1)  varB(1)  varC(1)  varD(1)
  bbb-5p-6134   varA(1)  varB(1)  varC(1)  varD(1)
  abb-4p        varA(2)  varB(2)  varC(2)  varD(2)
  bbb-5p        varA(3)  varB(3)  varC(3)  varD(3)
  bbb-5p-mi-98  varA(3)  varB(3)  varC(3)  varD(3)
```

Any idea?
Thank you in advance

Peter

Comment: This is a duplicate question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818840/in-r-get-multiple-rows-by-splitting-a-column-using-tidyr-and-reshape2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows

Comment: @akrun this is not an exact dupe, the question here involves more than just splitting strings and stacking them vertically..

Comment: @mtoto Ohh, okay, reopened it.  I thought the two links provided have some links to this one.  Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in `base R`, using `lapply()` with a custom function. First, you split your character column on `"/"`, resulting in a list of vectors:

```
l <- strsplit(df$ID,"/")
```

Then you apply a user defined function to each element of `l` using `lapply()`:

```
l_stacked <- lapply(l, function(x) 
          if(length(x) > 1) { 
          c(x[1], paste0(x[1],"-",x[-1])) } 
          else { x })
```

The function first checks whether the vector has a `length > 1`. If so, it concatenates all elements with the first element, separated by `"-"`. If `length <= 1`, it means the string didn't contain `"/"`, hence it is returned as is. Finally we flatten our output using `unlist()` to be able to convert to `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(ID = unlist(l_stacked))
#            ID
#1       bbb-5p
#2 bbb-5p-mi-98
#3  bbb-5p-6134
#4       abb-4p
#5       bbb-5p
#6 bbb-5p-mi-98
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Sounds like this code do the job... However my point is how to link this new ID with the others variables of my data.frame?

Comment: can you elaborate please? this is not stated in your original question.

Comment: Let's say my initial data frame have 5 variables [ID, varA, varB, varC, varD]. What I mean is, every time I have this "/" I would like to duplicate the row. But keep the entire row. Then I am expecting to have a new data frame with something like [newID(1), varA(1), varB(1), varC(1), varD(1)] ..... [newID(n), varA(n), varB(n), varC(n), varD(n)]... Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>% mutate(i=row_number(),
                     ID = strsplit(ID,split='/')) %>%
              unnest() %>% 
              group_by(i) %>%
              mutate(ID=ifelse(ID==first(ID),first(ID),paste(first(ID),ID,sep='-'))) %>%
              ungroup() %>% select(-i)
### A tibble: 6 x 1
##            ID
##         <chr>
##1       bbb-5p
##2 bbb-5p-mi-98
##3  bbb-5p-6134
##4       abb-4p
##5       bbb-5p
##6 bbb-5p-mi-98
```

Notes:

1. First, create an indexing column `i` to group by later so that we can group each "root".
2. Use `strsplit` to split each row by `"|"`.
3. `tidyr::unnest` the result to separate rows.
4. `group_by` the created index `i` and then if the row is the first row, just return the root; otherwise, `paste` to prepend the root to the row with separator `"-"`.
5. Finally, `ungroup` and remove the created index column `i`.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("bbb-5p/mi-98/6134", "abb-4p", "bbb-5p/mi-98"
)), .Names = "ID", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
                 ID
1 bbb-5p/mi-98/6134
2            abb-4p
3      bbb-5p/mi-98
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1, ..`)) and create a column of rownames, grouped by 'rn', split the 'ID' by `/`, loop through the sequence of rows, `paste` the split elements based on the index.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE)[, unlist(strsplit(ID, "/")), 
         by = rn][, .(ID=sapply(seq_len(.N), function(i) 
             paste(V1[unique(c(1,i))], collapse="-"))) , rn]
```

---

Or an option with `dplyr/tidyr/tibble`.  Create the rownames column with `tibble::rownames_to_column`, separate the rows into long format with `separate_rows`, grouped by 'rn', we `mutate` the 'ID' by `paste`ing the elements based on the condition of length and remove the 'rn' column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyr)
rownames_to_column(df1, var = "rn") %>% 
         separate_rows(ID, sep="/") %>%
         group_by(rn)  %>%
         mutate(ID = if(n()>1) c(ID[1], paste(ID[1], ID[-1], sep="-")) else ID) %>%
         ungroup() %>%
         select(-rn)
 #         ID
 #        <chr>
 #1       bbb-5p
 #2 bbb-5p-mi-98
 #3  bbb-5p-6134
 #4       abb-4p
 #5       bbb-5p 
 #6 bbb-5p-mi-98
```